# I am using chai and mocha for testing APIs in nodejsand got error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')"

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

**I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')" continuously

Code of test file is

```
import server from '../app';
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';

//Assertion Style
var should=chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

let chaiServer;
let projectCount;
const HypersignAuthToken = 'token_value'
const projectData=
  {"projectName":"demo-test-26",
  "logoUrl":"http://localhost:3000",
  "fromDate":"2021-12-15",
  "toDate":"2021-12-18",
  "actions":[],
  "refereePoint":5,
  "referralPoint":10,
  "projectStatus":1}
  


describe('API testing /api/v1/project', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    chaiServer=chai.request('http://localhost:6006')
   // chaiServer = chai.request(server);
  });
  
  it('should be able to GET projectCount', (done)=>{
      chaiServer
      .get('/api/v1/project')
      .auth(HypersignAuthToken,{type:'bearer'})
      .end((err, response)=>{
          response.should.have.status(200);
          response.body.should.be.a('array');
          projectCount= response.body.length;
        done();
      })
     
    })

        it('should add (POST) new project', (done)=>{
                  chaiServer
                  .post('/api/v1/project')
                  .auth(HypersignAuthToken,{type:'bearer'})
                  .send(projectData)
                  .end((err, response) => {
                    response.should.have.status(200);
                    response.body.should.be.a('object');
                    response.body.should.have.property('_id');
                    projectData['_id'] = response.body['_id'];
            
                });
              });



})
```

In my `package.json` i have

I am getting error:-

API testing for /api/v1/project
should be able to GET projectCount:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')
at serverAddress (node_modules/chai-http/lib/request.js:282:18)
at new Test (node_modules/chai-http/lib/request.js:271:53)
at Object.obj. [as get] (node_modules/chai-http/lib/request.js:239:14)
at Context. (src/tests/investor.ts:70:8)
at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:464:21)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue in our project. Make sure to export the express app in your `app.js`, for example like this:

```js
export const app = express()
```

Then in your test, import it properly and adjust your definition of `chaiServer`:

```js
import { app } from '../app'
// in your `beforeEach` handler
chaiServer = chai.request(app)
```